# Seperating gelatin and dairy

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk, contemporary-halacha, kashering-kosherization, yoreh-deah

According to poskim  who hold gelatin is only as kosher as the animal whose bones are used (with whom I don’t personally agree) does the same meat dairy separation Halacha apply?

Or is there leniency regarding  waiting a shorter period of time after eating products with gelatin or heating gelatin up in milchig appliances?

Comment: Who are such poskim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Star K](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/1404/getting-into-continued-on-page-4-the-thick-of-things-gelatin/):

> As to the question regarding whether hides are considered to be meat, Horav Moshe Feinstein zt”l addressed this issue in Igros Moshe ([Yoreh Deah Vol 1 #37](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=917&st=&pgnum=52)). He writes that animal hides are not considered to be meat (prohibiting its mixture with milk) by Torah law; they are, however, prohibited with milk by rabbinic law. If they are dried and processed, the resulting gelatin is not included in this rabbinic prohibition. Therefore, gelatin produced from kosher slaughtered animal hides may be intentionally used with milk, provided that the hides are cleaned in order to remove any meat residue. Some opinions disagree with Horav Feinstein’s conclusion, most notably Horav Aharon Kotler zt”l, who concludes that gelatin produced from kosher hides is considered to be a meat product. However, there is room for leniency when dealing with gelatin that is derived from kosher hides, as the gelatin has little or no taste. Therefore, it can be nullified in pareve ingredients which would result in a pareve product